# Laplace pressure of a capillary bridge

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

Laplace pressure is given by $$\Delta p=\gamma \left(\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R'}\right)$$ where $R$ and $R'$ are the radii of the curvature of the surface.

Using the following diagram[image: capillary bridge]

the book I'm trying to learn from says the Laplace pressure of the drop is given by $$\Delta p=\gamma \left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{\cos(\theta_E)}{H/2}\right)\approx \frac{-2\gamma \cos(\theta_E)}{H}$$ with an angle $\theta_E<\pi/2$. How does the expression that replaces $1/R'$ become negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, the question seems to have changed while I was typing this answer!

Just to be clear: the liquid bridge is rotationally symmetric about the vertical line of the two arrows that are pointing towards one another. This is why $R$ is one of the principal radii of curvature.

The value of $R'$ is just trigonometry. Given the contact angle $\theta_E$ on the diagram, it's fairly easy to see that the radius of the circular interface shown on the diagram $R'$ satisfies $\cos\theta_E=\frac{1}{2}H/R'$.

The radius of curvature carries a sign: $R$ is with respect to a centre within the liquid, $R'$ is curving the opposite way, with a centre of curvature out in the gas phase. So, it gives a negative contribution to the Laplace pressure in this case.

---

[EDIT following OP comment]

Calculating the force is a bit subtle. It isn't just the Laplace pressure times the area of contact between liquid and plate.
This [chapter by Kralchevsky](https://www.lcpe.uni-sofia.bg/files/publications/2001/2001-26-Book11.pdf) (from his publication list, but also available in the book by Kralchevsky and K. Nagayama, *Particles at Fluid Interfaces and Membranes* (Elsevier, 2001))
describes how the force is evaluated at the mid-plane between the plates. There is a Laplace pressure contribution, which acts on the area $\pi R^2$ in your diagram, plus a liquid-vapour surface tension contribution, which acts on the circumference $2\pi R$. They go on to say that the force could be evaluated by taking any cross-section parallel to the plates, giving the same answer, but the mid-plane means that you don't need to worry about the angles at which the forces act. You could do it at the surface of the plate (with a larger cross-sectional area, as you say) but the surface tension force (at an angle) still contributes,
and the answer turns out to be the same.

Have a look at section 11.2 in that chapter.

Comment: Aha, yes, I had managed to wrap my head around the geometry of the situation not long after I had posted (and after scribbling all over a side of A4)! Does this mean that for a bridge that's bulging outwards both $R$ and $R'$ will be positive?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. So, just like a spherical droplet, where $R=R'$, both give positive contributions to the Laplace pressure. In principle this is possible if the contact angle exceeds $\pi/2$ (the fluid is in the "partial drying" regime, i.e. it dislikes the surface, as opposed to the "partial wetting" regime). I see a picture of this near the section "Convex capillary bridge" on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_bridges). I don't know how stable that arrangement is, however.

Comment: When calculating the force due to the pressure that glues the two plates together, should a different value of $R$ be taken to reflect the surface area in contact with the plates which will have a larger radius than the $R$ of the diagram?

Comment: I've added a few lines to my answer: we're discouraged from allowing the comments section to become an extended discussion!