# Which are the radii of curvature in the Laplace Pressure formula?

Tags: water, surface-tension, capillary-action

Laplace pressure is given by $$\Delta p=\gamma \left(\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R'}\right)$$ where $R$ and $R'$ are the radii of the curvature of the surface.

Using the following diagram[image: capillary bridge]

There are at least 3 radius of curvature in the capillary bridge as far as I understand:

1. The radius of the **cylinder of water** (represented in the picture).
2. The radius of the **meniscus** with a center outside the drop of water of the picture.
3. The radius of curvature where **water is in contact with the flat surface** (which would be infine, as it is a plane).

Since the formula only allows two radius, what are the radius we should apply to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dominant term by far is $\frac1R$ in which $R$ is the meniscus radius. From it you should, for complete accuracy, subtract $\frac{1}{R'}$ in which $R'$ is the (much greater) cylinder radius. This will give you the excess pressure  outside the water drop.

Comment: Thank you very much. In some cases, one of the radius is considered to be **infinite** -- se [here](https://tardigrade.in/question/if-two-glass-plates-have-water-between-them-and-are-separated-hbzdrdfb) for example. Is that because the cylinder curve is considered too large, therefore "infinite"? I previously assumed by infinite it was referring to the **flat surface** in contact with the glass. Kindly clear that up for me please? Thanks again a lot.

Comment: I would guess that many would take the cylinder radius as infinite. But whether or not that is a valid approximation is quite easy to determine. Simply compare $R$ and $R'$.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't properly link the image before. See [here](https://i.redd.it/z19r9sz8lkc61.jpg) an example.

Comment: Thanks! That clears things up. Anyway, it's correct to say that the **flat surface** doesn't compute as a radius in the original formula, correct? Just the water/air interface?

Comment: Agreed. As you say, you could treat the flat surface as a spherical cap of infinite radius.

Comment: Do you think you could help me answer this [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609461/laplace-pressure-in-a-bubble-or-film-of-liquid)? Thanks.

Comment: I already have done – I hope.

Comment: Thanks very, very much! Just to be clear regarding the **cylinder radius** in this question. I am referring to the liquid bridge being rotationally symmetric about the vertical line of the two arrows that are pointing towards one another (the R represented in the picture). That is the same "cylinder" you have mentioned correct? With the meniscus in the picture curving the opposite way? Kindly answer that and I'll ask no more of you :) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that very same cylinder radius. I'm sorry that my notation doesn't agree with that on your diagram. I should have looked more closely.

Comment: One last question if you allow (sorry): we are taking the cylinder radius to be exactly in the middle of the drop. If we were to take it **above or below**, the radius would be **larger**. Would that influence calculations? Only the radius at the precise middle applies?

Comment: I suspect that the differing cylinder radius as we go up or down through the liquid might make the meniscus depart very slightly from being circular in section, but I might well be wrong here. In any case – and this is the important point – the reciprocal of the cylinder radius is so small compared with that of the meniscus radius that including it is a 'correction term', and worrying about corrections to corrections is not wise. But I expect that you are concerned with *principles*. I'm afraid that I've reached the limit of my very limited knowledge here.

Comment: "the reciprocal of the cylinder radius is so small" -- by this, you mean the term 1/R, correct? Since the cylinder radius is actually bigger. Anyway, thanks a lot. If you happen to be interested, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/442621/laplace-pressure-of-a-capillary-bridge) I found might have relevant information.

Comment: "Since the cylinder radius is actually bigger." The point I was making was that the reciprocal cylinder radius (any one of the slightly differing cylinder radii!) is much smaller than the reciprocal of the meniscus radius.

Comment: Sorry, I believe you misunderstood me. The cylinder radii are actually **bigger** than the meniscus radius, right? It's the 1/R' (in respect to the cylinder radius) that is smaller. Please correct me if I'm wrong. And sorry in advance.

Comment: No, we agree. The cylinder radii are bigger than the meniscus radius, so their reciprocals are smaller.