# Laplace pressure in a bubble or film of liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, surface-tension

Apparently, Laplace pressure in a bubble or film of liquid is simply the **double** of what it would be if it was a solid shape (a drop of water, for example). It makes sense because a bubble or film of liquid have **two surfaces**, instead of one side like the solid shape. [This video](https://youtu.be/MT2kxGgM5c0?t=425) also just doubles it for a film of liquid in the shape of a cylinder.

[image: a]

However, since one side the radius of curvature is curving **one way**, and the other side it's curving the **opposite way**, shouldn't it interfere with calculations (say, one positive term and another negative in the other surface)?

Does Laplace Pressure formula not compute signs (positive and negative) in this way perhaps?
Any clarifications are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[...] since one side the radius of curvature is curving one way, and the other side it's curving the opposite way [...]" No: the centres of curvature of the inside surface of the bubble, and of the outside surface, are both on the inside of the bubble – at its centre, in fact!

An example of when you needed to *subtract* reciprocals of radii of curvature was the example you asked about the other day: a droplet squashed between two flat plates.